# Android - getHostName() returns app name?

Tags: android, dns, lookup, inetaddress

In the android app I am working on, I am simply trying to get host names corresponding to ip addresses.

```
private class hostLookUp extends AsyncTask<InetAddress, Integer, String>{
    protected String doInBackground (InetAddress...ip){
        int count = ip.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            String hostName = ip[i].getHostName();
            if (isCancelled()) return "ERROR";
            else return hostName;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code of code of importance to me is

```
String hostName = ip[i].getHostName();
```

The only reason it is implemented withing AsyncTask is because android will not let me call that function within the main thread.
The previous code is used in a subroutine which includes the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < connectionCount; i++){
    statusList[i][0] = addressList[i].toString()  + "(" + new hostLookUp().execute(addressList[i]) + ")";;
    temp = connectionStatus (statusList[i][1]);
    statusList[i][1] = temp;
}
```

At this point in the subroutine, connectionCount is the number of ip addresses stored in an array of InetAddress. In this piece of code, I have a String array which will hold the ip adress converted to a string along with the host name in the first element of the array. In the end, position [0] will hold ip addresses and host names for all InetAddresses in the original array. Looking at the documentation, InetAdress.toString() should provide the host name anyways, but it does not do that. What does end up happening is I get

```
"/0.0.0.0(com.example.Test.MainActivity$hostLookUp@42244450)"
```

Where 0.0.0.0 is whatever IP address comes up and 42244450 is just some number that keeps changing. I just want the correct host name to appear, why does the app name show up instead?